# How to play music in Metro using file URL mechanism

Tags: c#, xaml, media, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to play Music Library files using file URL, that I will set to MediaPlayer object in a XAML c# object.

I constructed URI as followed

```
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(track.Id);

return new Uri("file:///" + file.Path);
```

URI looks like this: streamingUri = {file:///C:/Users/user/Music/04 - A Train Makes A Lonely Sound.mp3}

I need URL based scheme to play so that I can reuse same logic for web streaming too.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at 
[this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be). It should give you some ideas of how to do media playback from file.

While I notice you are saying you need a URI-based, you should use a stream for a local file. The only part you need to extract is a call to set the MediaElement's Source. You can just make a function with 2 overrides and it should be relatively clean.

So, for a web stream:

```
void SetMediaElementSource(Uri webStreamUri)
{ 
    MyMediaElement.Source = webStreamUri;
}
```

And for a local file:

```
void SetMediaElementSource(StorageFile file)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read); 
    MyMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType); 
}
```